# csv file with millions of record to process using java in minimum time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a database table and has 2 billion records in it and wanted to find duplicate records by reading each line and keep only unique records Then update one of the parent table with new adr_id  wherever old adr_id was being used
e.g.

**Before Address**

| adr_id | ver_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | newYork |
| 12 | 0 | Washington |
| 13 | 1 | Washington |
| 14 | 1 | newYork |
| 15 | 2 | Washington |

Result file should have unique records as below

**After Address**

| adr_id | ver_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | newYork |
| 101 | 0 | Washington |

Is there any standard framework in java which can help me to process
2 billion records in parallel with minimum time ?
E.g. Following are the facts of Records in a file

1. Each line in a file represent a record
2. address column value is a decision field for considering duplicate record.

Note : I am planning to export 2 billion records from parent and child tables in csv and since Java has better control for processing business logic I am biased towards Java as compare to sql

Comment: You title says CSV but your question says "database table". If that data is already in a database, I would do it at database level (group by, select into etc.)

Comment: @umang, please think about what data structure in java may efficiently hold 2 billion of records (hint: 2 billion ~= java.lang.Integer#MAX_VALUE )

Comment: @ChristophDahlen yes Data is there in database and require to perform some business logic e.g. identifying duplicate record and write only unique records to file also update parent record with newly created id of unique record

Comment: I don’t see how your “before” data leads to your “after” data.

Comment: Ok I wish to delete all duplicate records e.g. address=newyork to single record in after address table and it will have new adr_id

Answer (score 0):

The problem with finding duplicates in a dataset is that the duplicate-finding code needs to always have access to the entire dataset at all times, so as to be able to tell for every record if the same record has been encountered before. Clearly, this is untenable when a huge number of records is involved, because they will not all fit in memory.

Problems of this kind tend to be solved using hash-codes.

A hash-code essentially acts as a 'digest' of the information contained within a record, and although it cannot tell us for sure whether two records are identical, it can tell us for sure whether two records are different. So, it allows us to break our dataset down into small "buckets" where all records in a certain bucket are guaranteed to be different from all records in all other buckets. Then, we can process each bucket individually, effectively having broken the problem down into many smaller problems, each one of which will hopefully<sup>1</sup> fit within memory.

A very rough algorithm follows. This algorithm can be greatly improved upon, (optimized,) I am just showing it here to illustrate the general idea.

- For each record:

  - Compute its hash-code.
  - Create a "bucket" file if it does not already exist, using the hash-code as filename.
  - Append the record to the bucket file.
- Then, for each bucket file:

  - Read the entire bucket file into memory.
  - Scan for duplicates.

Since each bucket is independent, we can process many of them in parallel if we want to.

---

<sup>1</sup> I say "hopefully" because whether this will work or not depends on the content of your dataset. If your 2 billion records consist of only 2 different records, then you will have only 2 buckets of 1 billion records each, and this will not work either. But if you have sufficient variety in your data, meaning that you are not suffering from any pathological duplication scenarios, then it will work.

Comment: Bucket option looks promicing and I did checked but isn't opening file every time ,checking if it exists and if it does write line to it and close is costly ?
As I have to do this evey time and CANNOT keep too many files open ?

Comment: Yes, this would be very costly.  To overcome this problem, you need to reduce the range of hash-codes to match the number of files that you can open. For example, if you can only open 1000 files, then `hashCode = hashCode % 1000` will give you a hashCode in the range between 0 and 999.